# Maven rpm plugin does not like 'executable' as a directory path name

Tags: maven, plugins, rpm

In the source mappings, I specify many different directories. All works well.

However if I specify the directory which has the name executable the RPM plugin returns an error code of 1. The files strangely enough are still copied  to the RPM buildroot, but the RPM plugin overall fails. I renamed the directory to 'lib' and it builds fine.

Is the executable a reserved word or keyword of some sort??? The mapping below causes the build to fail. I have checked spelling and that is fine. The path exists. So why is it failing???

```
<mapping>
    <directory>/executable</directory>   //rpm directory
    <filemode>0644</filemode>
    <sources>
       <source>                                     
         <location>/path/to/directory/executable</location> // local dir under target
       </source>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Can you give the full pom, the version of rpm plugin and the full error message?

Comment: My foolish error, seems that I had binaries declared and noarch specified hence the error. Resolved now. Thanks anyway.